# I'm receiving 'JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, jsx

I'm building a application that gets an input from the user using buttons and create a array but when i try to display the array, it gets an error of JSX element type.

```
import { Delete } from "lucide-react"

export function PasswordButtons(){

const test = document.getElementById('passButon') as HTMLButtonElement;

let CharactersAdded:HTMLButtonElement[] = [test]

    const addUserPassword = (e : React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        CharactersAdded.push(test)
    }

    const eraseCharacter = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        CharactersAdded.pop();
    }
```

The user is supposed to click on these buttons and form a password

```
return <div> 
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}> ❤️ </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button className="passButton" onClick={addUserPassword}>  </button>
<button onClick={eraseCharacter}>
<Delete className="DeleteButton"/>
</button>
<br />
```

I've tried to display the array here

```
<p>
    <CharactersAdded />
</p>

</div>
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error traceback so that we can help you. It would also be convenient if you create a runnable snippet. For example, using https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-new.

Comment: The problem is `<CharactersAdded />` - `CharactersAdded` must be a (class or function) React component for that to work. Yet in your case it's an array of DOM elements. This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact error you are getting regarding call signature is because `CharactersAdded` is an array, but you are treating it like a component.

Under the hood, React will be attempting to do `React.createElement([])`. Normally, say for `<div />` React would do `React.createElement('div')`.

I think you are trying to push a character into an array, and then print that array to screen. To do that, you could do:

```
const charactersAdded = ['a', 'b', 'c'];


return <div>{charactersAdded.join('')}</div>
```

However, doing that won't fix the rest of the issues in your script:

- `getElementById('passButon')` but you don't have any elements with that id, only elements with class name
- you shouldn't really be referencing elements like that in react (except for extreme cases)
- You are pushing the same test value (`CharactersAdded.push(test)`) instead of basing it on the clicked button

I think overall, you are looking for a solution like:

```
const PasswordButtons = (props) => {
  const { password, setPassword } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, "❤️"])}> ❤️ </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => [...s, ""])}>  </button>
      <button onClick={() => setPassword((s) => s.slice(0, -1))}>
        delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <PasswordButtons password={password} setPassword={setPassword} />
      <pre>{password.join("")}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codepen.io/chrisk7777/pen/NWJwdzq?editors=0010

Note: There are probably cleaner ways to avoid the repetition, but the example is to show the OP a solution extended from their current code.